# OpenCV and Matplotlib not returning bounding box on object detection Python script

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, tensorflow, matplotlib

I am experimenting with openCV and object detection using Python 3.6 on Ubuntu Linux 18.04.  I have found this simple Python code at [this website](https://towardsdatascience.com/object-detection-with-less-than-10-lines-of-code-using-python-2d28eebc5b11) that claims to accomplish image detection.

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cvlib as cv
from cvlib.object_detection import draw_bbox
im = cv2.imread('/home/gerry/Pictures/guyonstreet.jpg')
bbox, label,conf = cv.detect_common_objects(im)
output_image = draw_bbox(im, bbox, label, conf)
plt.imshow(output_image)
plt.show()
```

I have installed the necessary libraries without issue as shown on the website.  I can run the code without errors.  Unfortunately the resulting image fails to show the expected bounding box identifying the object.  Below is a screenshot of what the code returned when I ran the experiment on a person.  I get similar results when I use an image of fruit.
Why is my code not returning the bounding box identifying the object?

[image]

Comment: The draw_bbox is part of cvlib. So try prefacing with cv. before draw_bbox as `output_image = cv.draw_bbox(im, bbox, label, conf)`

Comment: adding cv. to draw_box returned the following error     builtins.AttributeError: module 'cvlib' has no attribute 'draw_bbox'.

Comment: See https://www.cvlib.net. Add `from cvlib.object_detection import draw_bbox
`